# I cannot accept an answer

Tags: bug, voting, google-chrome, ajax

I cannot cast a vote or accept answers on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but on all other Stack Exchange sites it is working fine.

> [image]

I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: I notice that Shog's avatar isn't loading either.

Comment: I just tried to downvote Shog (automatic reaction) and that didn't work on that post either. Wait reversed the downvote because it did seem to stick - got the error but after a refresh it was still there.

Comment: Click F12 --> Network --> click upvote. Click the "/posts/239819/vote/2" item and post here the Response contents. Example for valid response: `{"Success":true,"Warning":false,"NewScore":1,"Message":"","LastVoteTypeId":2,"Refresh":false,"Transient":false}`

Comment: It must be Shog's way of preventing people from voting for him!!